# Construct OPAMP circuit for given inputs and output

Tags: operational-amplifier

Here is my task:

Construct circuit ??? which uses power supplies +12V and -12V and gives output voltage:

[image]

Here is circuit:

[image]

I solved it using 4 opamps:

First opamp scales V3, second integrates V4, third sums the results of the prior two circuits and fourth inverts signs in sum (output of third opamp).
Can this problem be solved using single opamp?

Comment: Can you explain the fomula in your question i.e. what is "ms"

Comment: milliseconds probably :)

Comment: Input voltages are: http://oi58.tinypic.com/2s6oxgk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're allowed any ideal component (not just practical components), you can solve this with one op amp. I'll give two hints:

1. Remember that the inverting summing configuration actually works by summing currents.
2. What device produces a current proportional to the integral of a voltage?

Comment: Yes, I'm allowed to use ideal components. Related to your second hint, inductor?

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution.................. 
[image]

Comment: You need to include some explanation. For example, what do the resistor and capacitors do, and what values should be chosen for them?

Comment: This is probably more practical than the solution I had in mind if V3 has no DC component. But if you also want gain of -2 for the DC component of V3, this won't work.

Comment: @The Photon, I would like to see your solution of this problem.

Comment: @Null, using this configuration we get exactly form of Viz. I will write values for elements.

Comment: @hari, To get my version, replace R1 with an inductor. Replace C1 and C2 with resistors.